# Simple HTML DOM seems to go in infinite loop, stops on next_sibling() and parent() method calls

Tags: php, web-scraping, simple-html-dom

After searching web few times, I found that Norton SafeWeb is not providing any API to developers to check if website is safe or not. I'm trying to retrieve information by scrapping. Here is the code that should return safe, caution or warning message. But somehow it gets stuck at the below mentioned line. Any solution?

```
$url_input = "http://www.google.com";    
$html = file_get_html('http://safeweb.norton.com/report/show?url=' . $url_input);
$rating_image_div = $html->find('.big_rating_wrapper');
$parent = $rating_image_div->parent(); // <-- it stucks here...
$required = $parent->children(3);
$result = $required->plaintext;
echo $result;
```

A part of html where this code targets:-

```
<div class="span3">
                <div class="paddingTop30 tAlignCr">

                    <div class="big_rating_wrapper">
                        <img src="/images/responsive/icons/norton-rating-big.png" alt="icoSafe" class="big_clip icoSafe">
                    </div>
                    <div class="clear"></div>

                        <b>SAFE</b><br>

                    <div class="hidden-phone">              


                        <a href="/help/site_owners">Site Owner? Click here</a>


                    </div>      
                </div>              
            </div>
```

Comment: You may select the div of class 'span3' using the XPath expression `//div[@class="span3"]/div/div[@class="big_rating_wrapper"]`, rather than matching the `div.big_rating_wrapper` and after checking for its parent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you'll want to change

```
$html->find('.big_rating_wrapper');
```

to

```
$html->find('.big_rating_wrapper', 0);
```

otherwise you get an array.